# Movie where a prisoner escapes from a crashed ship on a desolate alien planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, sy-fy

The movie starts off with a crashed ship on a desolate alien planet. This ship was holding a prisoner who escapes and the guards on the ship have to find and bring him back. BOOM plot twist the guards are humanoid aliens and the prisoner is the last human alive.

Comment: You've tagged this with [[tag:sy-fy]], does that mean you saw it on that channel? When did you see this? Was it new then?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like the 2010 film, *[Hunter Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_Prey)*

[image: Movie poster for Hunter Prey]

> A group of elite interstellar commandos crash lands on a planet while transporting an alien prisoner. Amidst shifting loyalties among the group, they must track down and recapture the escaped creature, alive. The escaped prisoner sets traps and picks off the commandos one by one. When only Commander Karza and Lieutenant Centauri 7 are left, Centauri suggests they kill the prisoner, but the commander insists that he be taken alive, regardless of the mounting cost. The two engage each other in a tense standoff, and the commander reveals that the prisoner, the last survivor of a planet destroyed during a war, has threatened to destroy their planet in retaliation.
>
> The standoff is interrupted when the commander is killed by a sniper shot. The prisoner declines a shot on Centauri and ambushes him. After he knocks the Sedonian unconscious, the prisoner reveals himself as a human. The human steals Centauri's supplies but leaves him alive. The human attempts to access the Sedonian computer database through a stolen communications device but is denied access. Centauri and the human, now able to communicate with each other, discuss the background of the war: Earth was destroyed because it accepted refugees of a Sedonian enemy. When a bounty hunter lands on the planet and attempts to take the human alive, Centauri intercepts him and captures the human, Lieutenant Orin Jericho.

### Trailer

Film found with a search for `film prisoner crashed ship "last human"`

Comment: If this is your answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.